# Laravel - How decrypt value of cookie

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello i need to decrypt value of cookie.
My code to create and destroy:

```
  public function setSession($id){
      Cookie::queue('userId', $id, 10000);
  }

  public function destroySession(){
      Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('userId'));
  }
```

But i need to get value of cookie without encrypt.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write code for me. I ask you to help me with understanding the problem.

I try: Crypt::decrypt(Cookie::get('userId')); - but was error: 'The payload is invalid.'.

Comment: `Cookie::get('userId')` already decrypts internally. You shouldn't need to decrypt unless you've encrypted somewhere else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In web request context cookies are usually automatically encrypted and decrypted by the **EncryptCookies** middleware. So easiest option would be just to enable this middleware (and it's enabled by default in Laravel).

If you need to decrypt any value manually, the following will do the trick:

```
// get the encrypter service
$encrypter = app(\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter::class);

// decrypt
$decryptedString = $encrypter->decrypt($encryptedString);
```

Check the code of the **EncryptCookies** middleware to learn more about what it does internally.

Comment: This is giving me 500 server error: `[2018-11-13 05:52:26] local.ERROR: Uncaught ErrorException: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 2 bytes in C:\xampp\htdocs\bflysoft_ico\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php:149`

Comment: @AhmedNumaan you might want to use `\Crypt::decryptString($encryptedString)` instead.

Comment: @mul14 You should post your answer as solution. Thanks!

Comment: I tried but it is gives the same error message I pasted above in comments. Looks like it is not supported by Laravel. There're might be some other purpose of this function.

Comment: Looks like your APP_KEY is invalid, Run "artisan key:generate"

Comment: // decrypt
`$decryptedString = $encrypter->decrypt($encryptedString);`
replace this with 
`$decryptedString = $encrypter->decrypt($encryptedString, false);`

By default `decrypt` tries to deserialize the value, and yours is not serialized and thats why you get the error

Answer (score 10):

By default Crypt::decrypt tries to deserialize the value, and yours is not serialized and that's why you get the error. You need to pass a second argument like:

```
Crypt::decrypt(Cookie::get('userId'), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

 
try {
    $decrypted = Crypt::decryptString(Cookie::get('cookie_name'));
} catch (DecryptException $e) {
    // ...
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/encryption